# Cannot get gunicorn to use Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, flask, gunicorn

I have Ubuntu+NGINX+Gunicorn with a virtual environment that works with Python 3 setup but my Flask app still runs as 2.7.6.  I have methodically followed the instructions but I cannot find a resolution.

**Gunicorn config file**

```
[program:app-server]
command = gunicorn app:app -b localhost:8000
directory = /home/www/app-server
user = appuser
```

**Project directory structure**

```
app-server    
----app.py
----venv (virtual environment)
```

Comment: That looks more like a supervisord configuration than a gunicorn config file.

Comment: You need to install it using ```pip3``` (or sometimes ```pip3.4```). So run ```pip uninstall gunicorn``` (if you don't need a python 2.6/2.7 version), and run ```pip3 install gunicorn```. If you ignored that uninstall part or are not allowed to because it is not your server alone, not to worry, just run ```which gunicorn -a```. The one you are using might not be the right one. I had had to use something like ```/opt/python-3.4.2/bin/gunicorn``` before (on CentOS). I know you said Ubuntu, but you never know!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Gunicorn is itself a Python application; the Gunicorn PPA only publishes *Python 2* versions.

You'd install Gunicorn into Python 3 instead (using `pip`, preferably into your virtualenv) and run that version:

```
/home/www/app-server/venv/bin/gunicorn
```

Comment: Feeling very saddened that this just doesn't work for me no matter what I do.  Locally it works without issue, but when I deploy it does not.

Comment: @CatManDo: *doesn't work* isn't much of a problem description. Can you *manually* start the Gunicorn server (the one in the virtualenv) on the remote server? If not, what happens instead? Etc.

Comment: I am using NGINX as a reverse proxy, but if I command line gunicorn app:app -b localhost:8000 which is the port being used my app still prints out 2.7.6 as the version of Python when I call sys.version.

Comment: @CatManDo: but just plain `gunicorn` runs the *system installed Gunicorn*, not the one installed in your virtualenv.

Answer (score 9):

Although the question is more than a year old, but i figured i should add my answer in case any one come searching

open this file  "/usr/bin/gunicorn" with a text editor. In my case I used vim with sudo in other to be able to edit the file

then change the python version to python3
usr/bin/python2.7 will be usr/bin/python3

then change the version number in the file to the version number of the gunicorn installed in virtual env. directory if both are not the same.
In my case the version number in the file was 17.0 but what i have is 19.6.0

Note that there are two places to change the version number in the file.

```
    #! /usr/bin/python3
    # EASY-INSTALL-ENTRY SCRIPT'gunicorn==17.5','console_scripts','gunicorn'
    __requires__ = 'gunicorn==19.6.0'
    import sys
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        sys.exit(
                  load_entry_point('gunicorn==19.6.0', console_scripts, 
                   'gunicorn')
                )
```

Comment: If you want to run the gunicorn installed in the venv, you should run the gunicorn in the venv, not make the system installed gunicorn look like the venv version.

Comment: @NikolayFrick it's not exactly an elegant solution to need to edit library files.