# python3 Error with opening csv file when running app with gunicorn

Tags: python-3.x, flask, gunicorn

When running my app with a gunicorn upstart, I get:

`TypeError: 'newline' is an invalid keyword argument for this function`

When I run it from the command line, however, I have no problem.

I've seen solutions that indicate `newline` should be in the file opening, not with the `csv.writer`. As you can see though,  I do indeed have it in the file opening.

**To recreate:**

1. save `my_app.py` to /home/--your home--/
2. `chmod u+x /home/--your home--/my_app.py`
3. save `my_upstart.conf` to /etc/init/
4. edit `my_upstart.conf` to replace  with your home dir
5. `sudo service my_upstart start`
6. `curl localhost:5001/vis` -H "Content-Type: text/csv"
7. `sudo cat /var/log/upstart/my_upstart.log`

In `my_upstart.log`, you will see the`TypeError` mentioned above

**my_app.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
from flask import Flask, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/vis/', strict_slashes=False)  
def vis():
    with (open('~/test.csv', mode='w', newline='')) as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5001)
```

**my_upstart.conf**

```
description "Gunicorn config file for serving the Wellness app"

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]

respawn
setuid ubuntu
setgid ubuntu

script
    cd /home/<your home>/
    exec gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:5001 my_app:app
end script
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

gunicorn was using python 2 and it's corresponding distribution package, wheras I'm using python 3.  Followed these steps to fix:

1. `sudo pip3 install gunicorn`
2. in `/usr/bin/gunicorn`,

   - edited first line to read `#!/usr/bin/python3` (instead of `python`) and
   - changed the gunicorn version anywhere it appeared to match what `gunicorn --version` says.

Answer (score 1):

Compare the documentation of `open` for Python version 2 and 3 and you will note that there is quite a bit of difference in what parameters can be passed.  In particular the parameter `newline` is not available in Python 2.

So my guess is that when gunicorn runs it will pick up a version 2 Python executable.

See [Cannot get gunicorn to use Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27589142/cannot-get-gunicorn-to-use-python-3#27589327) for more details.